# How to compile selenium python script into a standalone executable

Tags: python, selenium, py2app

I have tried pyinstaller, and py2app. After compiling the code using py2app, the executable won't open. Does selenium  cause this error?
Here is the source code of setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['breadpurchase.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages': ['httplib2', 'requests', 'selenium'] #this should be all I have to include right?
    }
setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The executable fails to run and I get a bunch of error's in the console. I think it might involve the chrome webdriver.
 Thanks in advance!

It can't seem to find these modules.
Modules not found (conditional imports):

```
 * http (requests.compat)
 * http.cookies (requests.compat)
 * urllib.parse (requests.compat)
 * urllib.request (requests.compat)
```

The console shows the following:
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoyy1.png)

Comment: What errors exactly?

Comment: Please share your console output. Also, why would you want to make it into executable? Isn't it better to simply run the script?

Comment: I want to send it to a friend so he can use it without the required dependencies.

Comment: Console output added!